# The time complexity of nested loops with a constant

Tags: algorithm, big-o

If we have a loop with like below and we know that c=5:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < c; i++ )
{
  // some logic
}
```

We get O(1).

if we have another loop:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < n; i++ )
{
  // some logic
}
```

We get O(n),

but what happens if we have nested loops like:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < n; i++ )
{
   for ( int j = 0 ; j < c; j++ )
   {
     // some logic
   }

}
```

what would be the time complexity of that?

Comment: `O(1)` times `O(n)` yields `O(n)`

Answer (score 2):

If both were O(n), you would be executing inner O(n) n-times, giving O(n*n) = O(n^2).
Since one is O(n) and the other is O(1), you're executing O(1) n-times, giving O(n*1) = O(n)

So, time complexity would be O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Those both loops have complexity of O(c*n).

Comment: There is no `O(c*n)` complexity, it is just `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity is the time taken by the code to execute. So in case of nested loops that you mentioned the time taken by the code to execute will be `c*n`.

Also the time complexity is represented in [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). So it will depend on the size of `c`.

If `c` is a constant like **1** or **5** then the overall complexity will be **`O(n)`** (because **O(constant * n)** = **O(n)** ). However if `c` is of the order of `n` (i.e. *c=n*), then the complexity will **`O(n*n)`**.